# Ошибка при установке пакетов в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Установил Python 3.8 с официального сайта.
Хочу установить пакеты numpy, scipy, scikit-Learn.
Запускаю консоль и ввожу команду в Windows 7 и получаю ошибку.
Я совсем новичок в Python.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Проблема на этапе подключения, скорее всего у вас [используется прокси](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44950994/python-m-pip-install-u-pip-errno-11004)

Comment: @Дмитрий Калинников Да, спасибо. Верно.

Comment: @SVD102, вы можете выложить содержание ошибки текстом, чтобы код и текст ошибки находились поиском?

Comment: @ДмитрийКалинников, может оформите это как ответ, чтобы вопрос не висел без ответа?

Answer (score 2):

Проблема на этапе подключения, скорее всего у вас [используется прокси](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44950994/python-m-pip-install-u-pip-errno-11004)

Укажите параметр `--proxy`

```bsh
pip install --user numpy --proxy http://username:password@proxy_url:port
```